# perl - convert cgi::session file into a hash

Tags: perl, session

I'm looking for a graceful way to read a cgi::session file into a hash, without loading the session and updating the access time. Here is what the data in the session file looks like...

```
$D = {
    '_SESSION_ETIME' => 283824000,
    '_SESSION_ID' => 'a07d36e7d9bc89d46a64ae271fe3709e',
    'userid' => '99999',
    '_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => '111.222.333.444',
    '_SESSION_CTIME' => 1432738284,
    '_SESSION_ATIME' => 1432740281,
    '_SESSION_EXPIRE_LIST' => {'~logged-in' => 120},
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'
};;$D
```

I need to generate a report of active and inactive sessions. I also need to keep track of the various browsers people are using.

EDIT: I did find comments in the Sessions.pm load() subroutine that eluded to passing any 'true' value as a 4th parameter and would make it read_only. I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: [`$session->dataref()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#dataref)?

Comment: dataref() works great, but it updates _SESSION_ATIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what `find` is for.

```
CGI::Session->find( sub {
   my ($session) = @_;
   ...
} );
```

As a side effect, this will delete expired sessions, but it won't change the access time (or anything else) of any of the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you read that session file, and then (if you really trust it) eval the contents, you'll end up with a scalar variable $D that is a reference to a hash of session key/value pairs.

That will not update the time stamp. Your time stamps are getting updated by CGI::Session.

I might be able to give you more specific advice if you told us what you want to accomplish by reading the session externally.

Comment: I need to generate a report of active and inactive sessions. I also need to keep track of the various browsers people are using.

Comment: So there you go. read the file, eval the file into the variables, iterate over them.  If you steal code form CGI::Session, then you won't have to write much. In fact, if you copy it, and then delete the timestamp update statements, you'll be most of the way there.

Comment: The code is actually in CGI::Session::Serialize::default